# ElasticSearch keyword fileds with normalizers do not work with wildcard query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
    "settings":{
      "analysis": {
        "char_filter": {
            "char_filter": {
                "pattern": "[^A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]",
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "replacement": ""
            }
        },
        "normalizer": {
            "normalizer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "char_filter": "char_filter",
              "filter": ["trim", "lowercase", "asciifolding"]
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "id":{ "type": "integer" },
    "a":{"type":"keyword", "normalizer": "normalizer"},
    "b":{"type":"keyword"}
  }
}
```

Documents:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "a":"one",
    "b":"one"
}

{
    "id":2,
    "a":"two",
    "b":"two"
}

{
    "id":3,
    "a":"three",
    "b":"three"
}
```

This query

`{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"b":"t*"}}]}}}`

matches two documents, as expected, but

`{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"a":"t*"}}]}}}`

matches none.
What's going on?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis turpis sagittis, blandit massa sed, tristique turpis.

Comment: Hi Richard, I just tried to reproduce this with Elasticsearch 7.5 but your last request returns two documents (like the first). It might be some bug on older versions (?)